# can I pass Predicate from querydsl to server?

Tags: spring, querydsl

I was reading the tutorial [here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl) from Spring and thought `Querydsl` would be interesting if it can be passed from client. That way client has total control on how to filter data and there would be only one generic method(filter) needed for the same dataset.

I do see that `Predicate`'s parent extends `Expression` which also extends `Serializable`, so it seems like I can serialize `Predicate`, but I got `stackoverflow` exception when trying to do so with `Jackson`. I also found that it has `stringValue()` method but can't find any way to have `Predicate` to read it.

Is it possible to have client decide how to construct `Predicate` object?